# How to match and display the data from more than one tables in android SQLite?

Tags: android, database

How to  get the data and display from more than one table in android? I have two tables namely students_name and another student_address. I have to get the table id and match it with second table. the data from tables to be displayed. How to achieve it using query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the rawQuery() method. Of course, you need to change the example SQL below.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT s.name, a.street FROM students_name s LEFT JOIN student_address a ON a.student_id = s.student_id", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `JOIN`. [Have a read of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

select name,address from student_address a,students_name n where a.id = n.id;

Answer (score 0):

You can use rawQuery() for tasks like that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Be aware to use JOIN with a WHERE statement for that.

Best wishes, Tim